# Are there any methodological challenges to study real-time social interactions?

Tags: social-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience, emotion, social-neuroscience

[image]

If the emotion of fear (for example) has evolved so that humans can react in an adapted way to danger, why would we be afraid in a **laboratory setting**, and would this fear be *similar* to that we experience when confronted with real danger?

Moreover they state that make-believe emotions are **qualitatively different from real emotions**

### Thus, how can we be in contact (in laboratory settings) with real emotions?

*References*

The Cambridge handbook of Human Affective Neuroscience, Jorge Armony and Patrik Vuilleumier, 2013

Comment: I think you should specify more. Of course you can register social interactions, a common form is the sociogram. In relation to emotions in laboratory: the laboratory environment is a valid environment for research for many reasons, another thing is that can be more or less critical with the generalization of the results (this will depend on the methodology used).

Comment: It is not understood what you mean by real emotions. It is not understood if you are going to work emotions in the laboratory or schemas or other constructs in relation to emotions (there are many other constructs such as prejudices, empathy, etc.). In the end I do not understand the question nor the development.